# Amchart add background image to XYChart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts

```
    let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
  chart.background.image = am4core.image("/static/img/bar-chart.png")
```

In Amchart i am trying to add background image over my chart.
But it is not working while i am doing this.

Please take a look if there is any way

Answer (score 0):

I modified the watermark tutorial

```
// Add watermark
var watermark = new am4core.Image();
watermark.href = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/cat.svg";
chart.plotContainer.children.push(watermark);
watermark.align = "right";
watermark.valign = "bottom";
watermark.opacity = 0.3;
watermark.marginRight = 10;
watermark.marginBottom = 5;
```

like this:

```
// Add watermark
var watermark = new am4core.Image();
watermark.href = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/cat.svg";
chart.plotContainer.children.push(watermark);
watermark.align = "center";
watermark.valign = "bottom";
watermark.opacity = 0.3;
watermark.height = 200;
watermark.width = 200;
```

Based on what do you need you might have to modify opacity, height and width.